# How to close a collapsed sidebar on click using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a collapsed sidebar that opens using an animated hamburger menu icon. However, I am unable to close it using JavaScript. My goal is to open and close my sidebar when I click on the animated icon. If there are any suggestions, that would be greatly appreciated! Hopefully, the code below is sufficient enough to recreate the problem.

HTML:

```
<h1>Sidebar Navigation</h1>

    <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
        <a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> &nbsp;Home</a>
        <a><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> &nbsp;Menu</a>
        <a><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> &nbsp;About</a>
        <a><i class="fa fa-group"></i> &nbsp;Careers</a>
        <a><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> &nbsp;Find a Store</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="openBtn" onclick="myFunction(this)"> 
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
        <p>Content pushed to the right when hamburger icon is clicked on which opens the sidebar.</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 6px 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #007CC7;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidebar a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
    color: black;
    transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}

a {
    color: white;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("content").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the internal logic of your myFunction function. Before using Vanilla.js to trigger the toggle event, first judge whether the element width needs to be adjusted this time.

You can click the Run code snippet or Expand snippet button below to see that the function fulfills your problem requirements..

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  adjustWidth("mySidebar");
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}

function adjustWidth(id){
  const btnDiv = document.getElementById('content');
  const e = document.getElementById(id);
  const eWidth = e.style.width;
  e.style.width = eWidth == '' ? "250px" : '';
  btnDiv.style.marginLeft = e.style.width;
}
```

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 6px 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #007CC7;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidebar a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
    color: black;
    transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}

a {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sidebar Navigation</h1>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> &nbsp;Home</a>
    <a><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> &nbsp;Menu</a>
    <a><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> &nbsp;About</a>
    <a><i class="fa fa-group"></i> &nbsp;Careers</a>
    <a><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> &nbsp;Find a Store</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="openBtn" onclick="myFunction(this)"> 
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Content pushed to the right when hamburger icon is clicked on which opens the sidebar.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution really helped, I definitely appreciate your feedback. I am still a beginner when it comes to JavaScript, so I am trying to learn as much as I can. To better understand this solution, do you mind sharing your thought process with me? It seems so simple, but I want to make sure that I can fully grasp this concept.

Comment: I don’t mind sharing my thought process. When designing a function, I suggest you first think about what results you need it to achieve before you start writing. For example, this question can be regarded as I have a button and call a function when I click it. The final result of this function is to achieve the result of opening or closing the sidebar. You have done half of it. You can already open the sidebar. The only thing left is to close the sidebar, because the same function is used to control the event regardless of whether it is opened or closed.

Comment: It is not divided into two functions to control opening or closing separately, so when you open the sidebar, you need to determine whether it needs to be opened, then how to judge the sidebar is open? If it has not been opened, you will find that its width is an empty string, and if It has been opened, according to your logic, it will be 250px, so according to these two conditions, we can easily judge the status of the sidebar, if it is open, we will close it, if it is closed, we will open it, thus realizing dynamic opening Or closed processing